# Expectation Hermite polynomials product $H_n(X) H_k(Y)$ when $X,Y$ are dependent Gaussians

Tags: hermite-polynomials

If $X,Y\sim N(0,1)$ with $E XY=\rho$ covariance, what is the expectation of their product after applying [probabilist's Hermite polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials) $E_{X,Y} H_n(X) H_k(Y)$?

My initial guess is $\rho^{2k}\delta_{nk}$ where $\delta$ is [dirac's delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Dirac%20delta,line%20is%20equal%20to%20one.). This would hold in the cases where $\rho=0,\rho=1$, ie, independent, or copy, as a direct result of orthogonality of Hermite's polynomials. However, I cannot prove or refute it in the general case.

Comment: I think you mean Hermit**e** polynomials

Comment: Hermits are people living in seclusion. Charles Hermite was a mathematician.

Comment: :)${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: apologies for the mistake, admittedly a cognitive flaw https://www.mrc-cbu.cam.ac.uk/people/matt.davis/cmabridge/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property can be deduced from [Mehler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehler_kernel). The formula states that
$$
E(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{\rho^2(x^2+y^2)-2xy\rho}{2(1-\rho^2)}\right)  = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{\rho^m}{m!}H_m(x)H_m(y)
$$
Observe that $E(x,y)$ is equal to $p(x,y)/p(x)p(y)$, where $p(x,y)$ is the joint PDF of $(X,Y)$, and $p(x),p(y)$ are PDF of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Therefore, we can take the expectation using the expansion
$$
\mathbf{E}_{X,Y} [H_n(X) H_k(Y)]= \int H_n(x)H_k(y)p(x,y)dxdy \\
=  \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{\rho^m}{m!}\int H_n(x)H_k(y) H_m(x)H_m(y) p(x)p(y) dx dy \\
= \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{\rho^m}{m!}\int H_n(x)H_m(x)dx\int H_k(y)H_m(y)dy \\
= (2\pi) n! \rho^n \delta_{nk} 
$$
where in the last line I used the orthogonality property $E_x H_k(x) H_n(x)=\sqrt{2\pi} n!\delta_{nk}$

This derivation has some constant factor $(2\pi)n!$ plus a different exponent $\rho^k$ than the one guessed in the question.